# How to replace the fitted value in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataframe called `new.cars`. I need to apply a linear regression formula to all the columns in my dataframe. There are thousands of columns in `new.cars`, so indicating each of them would not be possible in the formula. There are four columns, `PCAs` which will remain same in the formula for all other columns (columns other than `PCAs`) in which I want to apply this formula.

The formula for first column (column `mercedes`) is

```
fit1 <- lm(mercedes ~ PCA1 + PCA2+PCA3+PCA4, data=new.cars)
new.cars[,"mercedes"] <-fit1$fitted.values
```

and so forth for all other car columns..
What would be the best way to replace the column values with the `fitted value` (and also omitting NA values in the column, which means I don't want to change the NAs--as they are empty cells and need not be fitted)?

```
  new.cars<- structure(list(mercedes = c(1, 1, 1, 1), vw = c(1, 2, 0, NA), 
            camry = c(2, 0, 0, NA), civic = c(4, 1, 1, 1), ferari = c(2, 
            2, 2, 0), PCA1 = c(0.021122, 0.019087, 0.022184, 0.021464
            ), PCA2 = c(0.023872, 0.024295, 0.022471, 0.027509), PCA3 = c(0.000784, 
            0.001996, 0.003911, 0.006119), PCA4 = c(-0.004811, -0.003296, 
            0.001868, -0.001636)), .Names = c("mercedes", "vw", "camry", 
        "civic", "ferari", "PCA1", "PCA2", "PCA3", "PCA4"), row.names = c("S05-F13-P01.GT", 
        "S08-F10-P01.GT", "S08-F11-P01.GT", "S09-F66-P01.GT"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @akrun Sorry corrected that.

Comment: Do you want something like `lapply(names(new.cars)[1:5], function(x) lm(formula(paste(x, '~', paste0("PCA", 1:4, collapse="+"))), data= new.cars)$fitted.values)`

Comment: @akrun Yes that is correct. I want to replace the exact value (for example, if you substract `-8.409413e-16` from 2, it gives you 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may loop through the `names` of the 'new.cars' (that are not `PCA`), create a `formula` with `paste` using 'PCA' variables as independent variables, extract the 'fitted values' in a `list` ('lst').  We create a new dataset ('new1.cars') by subsetting the non-PCA columns from 'new.cars'.  Pad `NA` for `list` elements that have shorter length than the 'maximum' length of the elements in 'lst' and assign the output to the new dataset.

```
lst <- lapply(names(new.cars)[1:5], function(x) 
  lm(formula(paste(x, '~', paste0("PCA", 1:4, collapse="+"))), data= new.cars)$fitted.values)
new1.cars <- new.cars[1:5]
new1.cars[] <- lapply(lst, `length<-`,max(lengths(lst)))
```

#### Update

If there are columns with only `NA` values, we can create an exception to avoid doing the `lm` on that

```
lst <- lapply(names(new.cars)[1:5], function(x) {
                 x1 <- new.cars[[x]]
            if(all(is.na(x1))){
               NA } else lm(formula(paste(x, '~', paste0("PCA", 1:4, collapse="+"))), 
            data= new.cars)$fitted.values
         })
```

The rest of the steps are the same as above.

Comment: Why do I get this error : `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases`

Comment: @MAPK I am not getting any error with the example you provided.  But based on the error, it could be that all the elements are NA for a particular `list` element.  In that case, we can create an exception.

Comment: Yes there are a few columns with NAs only. How do we create exception for those? Thanks

Comment: This is the dataset generating error: `structure(list(mercedes = c(1, 1, 1, 1), vw = c(NA, NA, NA, NA
), camry = c(2, 0, 0, NA), civic = c(4, 1, 1, 1), ferari = c(2, 
2, 2, 0), PCA1 = c(0.021122, 0.019087, 0.022184, 0.021464), PCA2 = c(0.023872, 
0.024295, 0.022471, 0.027509), PCA3 = c(0.000784, 0.001996, 0.003911, 
0.006119), PCA4 = c(-0.004811, -0.003296, 0.001868, -0.001636
)), .Names = c("mercedes", "vw", "camry", "civic", "ferari", 
"PCA1", "PCA2", "PCA3", "PCA4"), row.names = c("S05-F13-P01.GT", 
"S08-F10-P01.GT", "S08-F11-P01.GT", "S09-F66-P01.GT"), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @MAPK I updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.